# Is there a way to simplify Java pattern matching to retrieve two pieces of data from a POST request?

Tags: java, pattern-matching, matcher, simplify

I'm new to Java and I'm shocked at how much code I need to retrieve two pieces of data (`queryKey` and `webEnv`) from a POST request. Is there a simpler or more optimal way to do what I have done here?

```
  String link = "https://eutils.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/entrez/eutils/epost.fcgi?db=nucleotide&id=" + id;
  URLConnection connection = new URL(link).openConnection();
  connection.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.11 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/23.0.1271.95 Safari/537.11");
  connection.connect();
  BufferedReader r  = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream(), "UTF-8"));

  String webEnv = "";
  String queryKey = "";

  // Put together string to be scanned to find patterns
  StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
  String line;
  while ((line = r.readLine()) != null) {
    sb.append(line);
  }
  String result = sb.toString();

  // Specify patterns to search for
  String queryKeyRegEx = "<QueryKey>(\\d+)<\\/QueryKey>";
  String webEnvRegEx = "<WebEnv>(\\S+)<\\/WebEnv>";

  // Create Pattern objects
  Pattern queryKeyPattern = Pattern.compile(queryKeyRegEx);
  Pattern webEnvPattern = Pattern.compile(webEnvRegEx);

  // Create Matcher objects
  Matcher queryKeyMatcher = queryKeyPattern.matcher(result);
  if (queryKeyMatcher.find()) {
    queryKey = queryKeyMatcher.group(1);
    System.out.println(queryKey);
  }
  Matcher webEnvMatcher = webEnvPattern.matcher(result);
  if (webEnvMatcher.find()) {
    webEnv = webEnvMatcher.group(1);
    System.out.println(webEnv);
  }
```

Comment: By the looks of your query, you are doing a HTTP GET request on an API and parsing the XML result. You are using standard Java libraries which, although fine, might need a lot of code to make them work. There are a few libraries I could suggest you use, and I can provide an example, if that's ok?

Comment: I would love to see an example @phss

Comment: I'd plug a SAX parser straight into the HTTP connection's input stream.  But that would also take quite a few lines of code.

Answer (score 1):

Check this out:

```
import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.Element;
import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;

import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import java.net.URL;


public class Try {

    private static Document loadTestDocument(String url) throws Exception {
        DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        factory.setNamespaceAware(true);
        return factory.newDocumentBuilder().parse(new URL(url).openStream());
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Document doc = loadTestDocument("https://eutils.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/entrez/eutils/epost.fcgi?db=nucleotide&id=1");
        NodeList nodeList = doc.getElementsByTagName("ePostResult");
        Element element = (Element) nodeList.item(0);
        String webEnv = element.getElementsByTagName("WebEnv").item(0).getTextContent();
        String queryKey = element.getElementsByTagName("QueryKey").item(0).getTextContent();
        System.out.println(webEnv);
        System.out.println(queryKey);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Java provides first class inbuilt support to deal with XML documents and it is called [JAXB](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jaxb/intro/). All you need is to create a bean class with required fields and use the code like below to unmarshall from XML to Java object.

```
JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(ePostResult.class);
XMLInputFactory xif = XMLInputFactory.newFactory();
InputStream stream = new ByteArrayInputStream(result.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
XMLStreamReader xsr = xif.createXMLStreamReader(stream);
Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jc.createUnmarshaller();
ePostResult ePostResult = (ePostResult) unmarshaller.unmarshal(xsr);

System.out.println("QueryKey->" + ePostResult.getQueryKey());
System.out.println("WebEnv->" + ePostResult.getWebEnv());
```

where you can declare your bean class:

```
@XmlRootElement
public class ePostResult {
    @XmlElement(name = "QueryKey")
    String QueryKey;
    @XmlElement(name = "WebEnv")
    String WebEnv;

    public String getQueryKey() {
        return QueryKey;
    }

    public String getWebEnv() {
        return WebEnv;
    }
}
```